# Jersey/JAX-RS clients that use Jackson to pass POJOs as entities

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I am trying to implement a RESTful web service client using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/)/JAX-RS:

```
public class MyClient implements Closeable {
    private Client client;
    private FizzResource fizzResource;
    // Several other resources omitted for brevity.

    // Ctor, getters and setters, etc.

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        client.destroy();
        client.getExecutorService().shutdown();
    }
}

public class FizzResource {
    private Client client;

    public Fizz saveFizz(Fizz fizz) {
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("whatever");
        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(???).post(???);
        if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
            // do something...
        } else {
            // do something else...
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I do not want to work with JSON; instead I want to work directly with my entities (e.g. `Fizz`). I would like to use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to automagically do the serialization between JSON and my entities (without me having to explicitly do the conversion inside each method), but I'm not seeing how this is possible/doable. Ideally my `saveFizz` method might look like:

```
public Fizz saveFizz(Fizz fizz) {
    WebResource webResource = client.resource("whatever");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").post(fizz);
    if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Errors are bad, mkay?");
    }

    Fizz fizz = response.extractSomehow();

    return fizz;
}
```

Assume my `Fizz` class is already annotated with the correct Jackson annotations (`JsonProperty`, etc.).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Jersey 1.x, so have a look at [the user guide for JSON/POJO support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#json)

**First thing:** We need to make sure you have the `jersey-json` module

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This module will have the needed `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter` that will read and write you POJOs to and from JSON

**Second thing:** We need to make sure we enable the POJO mapping support feature. Both with the server/application and with the client

Server with web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Server programmatic

```
public class MyApplication extends PackagesResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        getFeatures()..put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    }
}
```

See other [Deployment Options](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html#d4e188)

Client Config

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, 
                               Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
```

**Third thing:** We just need to make sure our resource method are annotated properly and we make the client call properly (to allow the correct writers/readers to be discovered).

For methods accepting JSON, it should annotated with `@Consumed("application/json")` and if the method also produces a response in JSON, it should also be annotated with `@Produces("application/json")`. So it depends on the semantics of your method, which annotations to include, it could be one or both.

For the client, as long as we have to correct configuration, extracting the Java Object, is just a matter of calling a `getXxx` with the Java type.

```
public void testGetFizz() {
    // Directly extact
    Fizz fizz = r.path("fizz").accept("application/json").get(Fizz.class);
    System.out.println(fizz);

    // Extract from ClientResponse
    ClientResponse response = r.path("fizz").
                     accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
    Fizz fizz1 = response.getEntity(Fizz.class);
    System.out.println(fizz1);
}
```

**Here are other pieces of code I used for my test**

```
@Path("/fizz")
public class FizzResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response postFizz(Fizz fizz) {
        System.out.println("==== Created Fizz ===");
        System.out.println(fizz);
        System.out.println("=====================");
        return Response.created(null).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getFizz() {
        Fizz fizz = new Fizz(1, "fizz");
        return Response.ok(fizz).build();
    }
}
```

Server config

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new PackagesResourceConfig("test.json.pojo");
resourceConfig.getFeatures().put(
                       JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Client config

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, 
                               Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
r = client.resource(Main.BASE_URI);
// r = WebResource
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use Jackson's ObjectMapper:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(response.getEntity(String.class), Fizz.class);
```

As long as Fizz is correctly annotated, this should do what you are looking for.

There are other options as well, which usually involve implementing custom providers.

Comment: Thanks @Calardan (+1) - but that is a standalone snippet of deserializing a JSON string into a `Fizz` instance. How would this work inside my actual `saveFizz` method above? What would I have to pass into the `webResource` methods? How would I extract the `Fizz` from the `response`? Thanks again!

Comment: You can obtain the String representation of the Response by calling
`response.getEntity(String.class)`
if you want to work on an InputStream instead, you can just use
`response.getEntityInputStream()`

For posting an instance of Fizz you can just use the follwoing:
`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
webResource.accept("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, mapper.writeValueAsString(fizz))`

This is a very basic solution to marschalling and unmarshalling JSON Strings.

Comment: As @peeskillet showed, more advanced solutions would configure Jersey's Client API or introduce custom providers. Pick the one that suits you most.

Comment: There's actually nothing "custom" about my solution. The module has the built in providers, which already uses Jackson and an ObjectMapper in its `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`. All my answer is showing is how to configure it to make it work :-)

Comment: You are right. Your solution does not involve any "custom" modifications. What I was referring to was using an own SerializationProvider if needed as an alternative option.

Answer (score 0):

If you include (supposing you use maven)

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

then you will have automagically conversion without setting up anything. You can write functions like:

```
@POST
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
public Activity createActivity(@Valid Activity activity) {

    return activityDAO.createActivity(vuser,activity);
}
```